# Instantiated ParticleSystem as GameObject not working in Unity c#

Tags: c#

Whenever the object is instantiated, it appears in the scene as per code but in the game scene nothing happens. I tried all the ways. Is there something wrong with my program? This has stopped me from doing what I have to do, and returning to my work:

this is my program:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public float ImpactForce = 70f;
    public float firerate = 15f;

    public Camera fpscam;
    public Camera scope;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleflash;
    public GameObject ImpactEffect;

    private float nexttimetofire = 0f;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && Time.time >= nexttimetofire)
        {
            nexttimetofire = Time.time + 1f/firerate;
            shoot();
        }
        void shoot()
        {
            muzzleflash.Play();
            RaycastHit hit;
            if(Physics.Raycast(fpscam.transform.position, fpscam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
            {
                Target target=hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
                if(target != null)
                {
                    target.TakeDamage(Damage);
                }
                if(hit.rigidbody != null)
                {
                    hit.rigidbody.AddForce(-hit.normal * ImpactForce);
                }
                GameObject ImpactGO = Instantiate (ImpactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation (hit.normal));
                Destroy(ImpactGO, 2f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the Particle System in the scene? If not, add it and link the object with the script. Otherwise, just check if the Particle System is linked to the script.

You can check in this part of Unity if the object is linked:

[image: you can check in this part of unity if the object is linked]

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping by the way. I added it in the inspector, should I have to bring the particle system anywhere in the scene. I thought instantiate will create the game object and place it in the coordinates we tell it to. But that’s not working.